# How to push a list of anonymous types to a list of defined types

Tags: c#

I have an IQueryable Anonymous type being returned from a query, of the form:

`EntityQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType1<g = Game, ghp = GameHasPlayer>>`

I'm trying to construct a class to accept this query result so I can manipulate it easily

```
public class GamesWithPlayers
{
    public Game game { get; set; }
    public GameHasPlayer gameHasPlayer { get; set; }
}
```

I've managed to squish the anonymous type to something more recognisable to me by using

```cs
var anonList = x.ToList() //Where x is the IQueryable of anonymous type`
```

I know how to get one instance of my containing class populated like so:

```cs
GamesWithPlayers a = new GamesWithPlayers() { game = anonList[0].g, gameHasPlayer = anonList[0].ghp };
```

but is there a way to put the entire `anonList` in to a new `List<GamsWithPlayers>`?

I tried casting

```cs
List<GamesWithPlayers> gamesWithPlayers = (List<GamesWithPlayers>)y;
```

But obviously there's no assigning `game = g, gameHasPlayers = ghp` and I have no idea what the syntax for that'd be :/

Comment: `.Select(anon => /*code that returns correct item type*/).ToList()` or avoid using anonymous types for this task if you can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to transform each element of a `IEnumerable<T>` to something else. This is exactly what `Select` does.

You have shown that given an object `x` of your anonymous class, you can create a `GamesWithPlayers` from it like this:

```
new GamesWithPlayers() { game = x.g, gameHasPlayer = x.ghp }
```

You can pass this expression to `Select`:

```
var gamesWtihPlayersList = 
    anonList
    .Select(x => new GamesWithPlayers() { game = x.g, gameHasPlayer = x.ghp })
    .ToList();
```

And this will be applied to each element in `anonList`.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. Thank you!